# Strongly typed c++ varargs

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a utility function in c++ 11 that adds an element of a single type to a vector. Most variable argument docs/guides I've found show a template with the `typedef` type, but I'm looking to only allow a single type for all the variable arguments (`const char*`). The following is the relevant snippet of code:

Item.hpp:

```cpp
// Guard removed
#include <vector>

class Item {
  public:
    Item(const char* n, bool (*optionChange)(uint8_t), const char*...);
  private:
    std::vector<const char*> options;
    void addOption(const char*);
}
```

Item.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Item.hpp"

void Item::addOption(const char* option) {
  options.push_back(option);
}

Item::Item(
  const char* n, 
  bool (*optionChange)(uint8_t),
  const char* opts...
): name(n), type(MENU_TYPE_OPTS), selectedOpt(0) {
  addOption(opts...); // Doesn't compile
}
```

Compilation of the above code fails with the message `error: expansion pattern 'opts' contains no argument packs`.

Comment: There are no "strongly typed varargs", it's just not part of the language. There are however [*template parameter packs*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) which might be used in a similar way.

Comment: I've tried parameter packs too, but somehow couldn't get it to compile when I provide a type instead of just using a generic type: `template<char*... T>`

Comment: What is `optionChange` used for? Please remove everything that is not relevant to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Template parameter packs, or optional function parameters. Don't use `char*` pointers are too tricky to handle, prefer `std::string` which supports most functionality like primitive types.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm developing for an embedded platform, so I'd rather my stack stay relatively intact. `std:string` has a bad habit of causing stack fragmentation and crashes, so I'm trying to steer clear of that as far as possible.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I left that in as I didn't want to change the constructor symbol too much, lest it affects the solution.

Comment: @CryptoAlgorithm Well, you shouldn't leave things in that we can't figure out what to do with. Anyway, you could just initialize the `options` `vector` directly from a parameter pack: https://godbolt.org/z/fneWvnzxb

Comment: @CryptoAlgorithm: The question was closed before I could post my long answer, so I'll just give you the working demo: https://godbolt.org/z/n69MaqT1e

Answer (score 5):

Use a variadic template. With variadic template, also all types can be different, but you can request that they are all the same via SFINAE

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename ...T>
std::enable_if_t< 
    std::is_same_v< std::tuple<const char*, T...>,
                    std::tuple<T...,const char*>>
    ,void>
foo(T...t) {}

int main() {
    const char* x;
    int y;
    foo(x,x,x,x); // OK
    foo(x,y,x); // error
}
```

This is based on a neat trick to check if all types of a variadic pack are the same type (i'll add the referene to the original when I find it). `std::tuple<const char*, T...>` and `std::tuple<T...,const char*>` are only the same type when all `T`s are `const char*`. `std::enable_if` will discard the specialization when the condition (all `T`s are `const char*`) is not met and attempting to call it results in a compiler error.

This is rather old fashioned and works already in C++11 (apart from the `_v`/`_t` helpers). I suppose in C++20 there are less arcane ways to require all `T`s to be `const char*`.

---

I missed that it is a constructor and you cannot do return-type-SFINAE on a constructor. It just needs to be a little more convoluted:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

struct foo {
    template <typename ...T,
              std::enable_if_t< 
                   std::is_same_v< std::tuple<const char*, T...>,
                                   std::tuple<T...,const char*>
                   >,
                   bool
              > = true>
    foo(T...t) {}
};

int main() {
    const char* x;
    int y;
    foo f1(x,x,x,x); // OK
    foo f2(x,y,x); // error
}
```

When the condition is met the last template parameter is non-type `bool` and has a default value of `true`. It's only purpose is to fail when the condition is not met (hence it does not need to be named).

Comment: Would this method work for constructors in the header file as well? Adding `std::enable_if_t<...>` before the constructor makes the compiler complain that `'enable_if_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type`. I added all the required includes too, no idea what's wrong.

Comment: @CryptoAlgorithm oh sorry. I missed that it is a constructor. Give me a second, I'll edit

Comment: *"I suppose in C++20 there are less arcane ways"*, as C++17 fold expression: `(std::is_same_v<const char*, Ts> && ...)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 or... `std::same_as<const char*> auto...`?

Answer (score -1):

You can't expand [variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) like [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). You either have to switch to another approach (like the parameter packs/[std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)) or rely on [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) of `<cstdarg>`:

```
Item::Item(const char* n, bool (*optionChange)(uint8_t), size_t opt_num, ...): name(n), type(MENU_TYPE_OPTS), selectedOpt(0) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, opt_num);
    
    for (decltype(opt_num) i = 0; i < opt_num; ++i) {
        const auto option = va_arg(args, const char *);
        std::cout << option << std::endl;
    }
    
    va_end(args);
    ...
}
```

Be advised that in this scenario, you don't have control over types of passed arguments, and the entire contract is supposed to be agreed verbally or in comments. The client code also should provide meta-data for the approach to be viable (i.e. in this example `opt_num` stores the number of strings passed)

---

##### EDIT

CPP community definitely  doesn't like the varargs thing, as my answer was instantly downvoted, so another, more C++ friendly solution is to replace varargs with `std::initializer_list`:

```
Item::Item(const char* n, bool (*optionChange)(uint8_t), std::initializer_list<const char *> options): name(n), type(MENU_TYPE_OPTS), selectedOpt(0) {
    for (const auto& option: options){
        std::cout << option << std::endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is not an appropriate typesafe approach one should take with C++

Comment: @AndyG i just make a distinction between concepts. What OP is using is not a parameter pack and if he wants to use variadic arguments, here is a way of doing so

Comment: OP says they want to allow only `const char*`. `va_args(args, const char*)` is rather assuming that they are `const char*` and hoping for the best

Comment: `std::initializer_list` seems interesting, I'll check that out too.